# Replicating data between two databases with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, replicate

Good evening everyone.

I'm looking for a way to replicate data between two database, would select some (or all) tables, probably all the data that are determined within these tables, and copy it to other tables with the same structure, but in different database . We use NHibernate, uNhAddIns, and searching the internet, I found something about ISession.replicate (), but could not find an effective documentation of how to use it.

We don't know yet how we're gonna do it, if it will copy some tables (pre-selected) when our application starts, I'm planning this. But i'll really be appreciated of any type of help. So, anyone have anything, tutorials, articles that could help in understanding this tool?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi! What was you solution in the end?
I'm having the same problem (trying to replicate a server database into a SQLite), initial shot was to use MS Sync framework, but it didn't fit our needs...